# Is java.sql.Date() and the mysql command sysdate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

is the `java.sql.Date()` and the mysql command sysdate gives exactly the same date time?

Comment: Vague question! java.sql.Date() is a class.

Answer (score 1):

The `SYSDATE` function gives the date and time of the database server. The `java.sql.Date` does not give any particular date - it must be initialized to a specific date, and it only stores the date, not the time. (Internally it does store a time component as well, but it's meaningless and you're supposed to ignore it.) If you create a `java.sql.Date` object with

```
date = new java.sql.Date(System.getCurrentTimeMillis());
```

or something equivalent and your database is running on a different machine, you may get a different date when you call `SYSDATE` if the clocks on the two machines are not synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

You will run the command `sysdate` on the DB system . It gives you the system date of the DB server.

[java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) is *A thin wrapper around a millisecond value that allows JDBC to identify this as an SQL DATE value.* It is different , it is a Java object which interfaces with the sql date. The JDBC driver will use the `java.sql.Date` object and format its data to an acceptable format while storing it in the DB and vice versa.

By itself it cannot give us a date until you feed it with some data, and it stores years, months and days while hour, minute, second and millisecond are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SYSDATE();
```

**Output:** 2013/07/26 04:16:55

**Default Format:** yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

```
Date a=new Date();
java.sql.Date d=new java.sql.Date(a.getTime());
System.out.println(d);
```

**Output:** 2013/07/26

**Default Format:** yyyy-MM-dd